# Resend order confirmation emails for some orders in Shopware 6

Tags: email, shopware6

Because of an error which is now fixed, our customers did not received order confirmation emails for a while.

Is there a way to resent the order emails for some orders once?

We know about [the plugin](https://store.shopware.com/fourt97412653336/bestellbestaetigung-erneut-per-e-mail-senden.html), but as this is supposed be needed only once, it's kind of overkill to install, test and deploy a plugin.

Are there some code snippets or a `bin/console` command to accomplish this task?
Or is it even possible via the admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define a flowbuilder flow to send order confirmation mails, but you'd to define an appropriate trigger action of course, that you can trigger yourself for the affected orders. After the oneshot command you could disable/delete the flow.
Not sure if this fits your needs...

Comment: Sounds like a very cool idea at first glance, but I did not find a proper trigger. I could use state changes, but then - of course - I have to change the other state which I'd rather not want. If we would use Shopware Professional we could use API trigger, but in the standard version there seems no nice manual trigger type

Answer (score 1):

You could [write your own CLI command](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-custom-commands) to re-fire the event when an order is placed.

```php
// $this->orderRepostitory - DI service `order.repository`
// $this->orderConverter - DI service `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\OrderConverter`
// $this->eventDispatcher - DI service `event_dispatcher`

$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria
    ->addAssociation('orderCustomer.customer')
    ->addAssociation('orderCustomer.salutation')
    ->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingMethod')
    ->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.country')
    ->addAssociation('deliveries.shippingOrderAddress.countryState')
    ->addAssociation('transactions.paymentMethod')
    ->addAssociation('lineItems.cover')
    ->addAssociation('currency')
    ->addAssociation('addresses.country')
    ->addAssociation('addresses.countryState')
    ->getAssociation('transactions')->addSorting(new FieldSorting('createdAt'));

// add a filter for the orders for which no mail has been sent before
$criteria->addFilter(new RangeFilter('createdAt', [RangeFilter::LTE => (new \DateTime('2020-01-01'))->format(\DATE_ATOM)]));

$orderEntities = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $context->getContext())->getEntities();

foreach ($orderEntities as $orderEntity) {
    $salesChannelContext = $this->orderConverter->assembleSalesChannelContext($orderEntity, Context::createDefaultContext());
    $event = new CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent(
        $salesChannelContext->getContext(),
        $orderEntity,
        $salesChannelContext->getSalesChannel()->getId()
    );
    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($event);
}
```

This should in theory also trigger the mails to be sent once more. Obviously try this with a test order before mass dispatching events like this. Also you should probably do this in smaller batches to avoid memory issues.

Comment: This wouldn't only resent the mail but could also cause other subscribers on this event - for example ERP exports - to re-trigger, right?

Comment: Yes, obviously anything that listens to the event. If you want to be sure you could take a look at the `FlowExecutor` and build a flow event with the `CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent ` to execute just the flows for that trigger.