# Shopware 6 dummy data for test mails

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I need to reproduce a scenario within the order confirmation email template where the billing address is missing.

It's an individual case which I can't reproduce by placing an order myself.

To reproduce that scenario I deleted all following orders until the one with the missing address in the mail were the latest.
I was thinking the template gets the information from the latest order but that wasn't the case.

So I am wondering where the mail templates get their values from.

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The dummy data is saved in the table `mail_template_type` in the column `template_data`.
I think the behaviour was changed in a release this year because of performance reasons. Before it was like you describe: the latest order was used. Actually I think it used still this column, but it was updated with every new order which isn't the case anymore.

EDIT: as noted in the comments below, the data is still updated by default on every order placed but there's an option to deactivate it and it is recommended to do so in a production environment.

Comment: The data is still updated by default on every order placed but there's an option to deactivate it and it is recommended to do so in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I added this to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the mail template in the `template_data` seems to happen during sending an email (`\Shopware\Core\Content\Flow\Dispatching\Action\SendMailAction::updateMailTemplateType`) - so the only way to reproduce an error with an old order seems to  be to resent this old order mail.

This needs a custom CLI command or a 3rd party extension:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73124996/288568